# Getting Data Subsets in CTREE() function in R

Tags: r, decision-tree

I have a dataset obtained as:

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
```

which contains the variable `y` (`y` is binary 0 or 1) and some regressor variables.

I want to apply the ctree technique on this data with the following requirements:

1. Of course I would need the tree plot (which I can do myself)
2. After that, I would need the segmented subsets of the data (as determined by running `ctree()`) in array format, i.e. if ctree partitions mydata into 6 smaller datasets, I need to output an array `CTree_Subsets` with 6 elements, each element being one of these smaller datasets.

Note that I need the actual smaller datasets in the array, and not just their characteristics/classification rules obtained from the tree. (Context: I'll need to run separate logistic regression models for each of these smaller datasets).